# False positive SonarQube violation on String concatenation in loop

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have some code looking like this (I replaced my business variables with generic ones):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    String suffix1 = retrieveValue1(i);
    String suffix2 = retrieveValue2(i);
    String tag = "prefix";
    if (suffix1 != null) {
      tag += suffix1;
    }
    else {
      tag += suffix2;
    }
    map.put(tag.toUpperCase(), "on");
}
```

What bugs me is that I receive the following SonarQube violation:

> Performance - Method concatenates strings using + in a loop

In my opinion this is a false-positive (because there is no real loop on a String here) but I'd like to double check first.

I could not find any similar case with my friend Google.

Is it a false-positive, or is there a real performance loss in my loop please?

Comment: Whenever your code does `tag += suffix1` it creates multiple String instances and that too in a loop, Hence the violation.

Comment: Well, you *could* do this: `new StringBuilder("prefix").append(suffix1 != null ? suffix1 : suffix2).toString()`...

Comment: But this doesn't answer any of the questions in the post, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SonarQube is probably getting confused about the use of `+=` inside the loop.

`String tag = "prefix";` is created inside the loop so there is no String concatenation inside a `for` loop and, technically, the warning is a false positive.

Note that you could still use `StringBuilder` to append both part of the tag, but you'd have to measure if it's necessary or not.

Comment: I am really surprised SonarQube doesn't filter variables created INSIDE the loop and then consumed by something else for this rule.
I got away by creating a StringBuilder outside the loop, instantiating and appending in the loop, and pushing the builder.toString(). The code is a bit more verbose, but SonarQube stopped crying...

Comment: @jdebon A note of warning though: don't become a slave of the tool. False positives are a reality and you can declare a violation as false positive in SonarQube. This might be better than reworking your code.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of that =) But in my case it was still a slight performance improvement, so I didn't mind. If the concatenation had happened all on the same line, I would have flagged as FP. Thanks =)

Answer (score -1):

Declare the String variables outside the loop. I think this might solve your problem.